# return sample date between min date and max date in R in a dataframe

Tags: r, stat

How to return sample date between min date and max date in R in a dataframe as an additional column?

```
Course MinEnrollmentDate MaxEnrollmentDate
Maths 3/11/2016 3/4/2016
Chemistry 6/11/2016 6/4/2016
Physics 9/11/2016 9/4/2016
English 12/11/2016 12/4/2016
Science 3/11/2017 3/4/2017
```

Comment: I think column names for `MinEnrollmentDate` and `MaxEnrollmentDate` have been interchanged.  Ideally, `MaxEnrollmentDate`  shold be >=  `MinEnrollmentDate`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` we can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(MinEnrollmentDate = as.Date(MinEnrollmentDate, format = '%m/%d/%Y'),
           MaxEnrollmentDate = as.Date(MaxEnrollmentDate, format = '%m/%d/%Y'), 
           sampleDate = sample(seq(MinEnrollmentDate, MaxEnrollmentDate, '-1 day'), 1))

df
#> Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      Course MinEnrollmentDate MaxEnrollmentDate  sampleDate
#>       <chr>            <date>            <date>      <date>
#> 1     Maths        2016-03-11        2016-03-04  2016-03-08
#> 2 Chemistry        2016-06-11        2016-06-04  2016-06-09
#> 3   Physics        2016-09-11        2016-09-04  2016-09-06
#> 4   English        2016-12-11        2016-12-04  2016-12-09
#> 5   Science        2017-03-11        2017-03-04  2017-03-06
```

Not sure if I got the format of your dates right, it's ambiguous, feel free to correct the `format=` part.
Data:

```r
df <-  read.table(text = 'Course MinEnrollmentDate MaxEnrollmentDate
                  Maths 3/11/2016 3/4/2016
                  Chemistry 6/11/2016 6/4/2016
                  Physics 9/11/2016 9/4/2016
                  English 12/11/2016 12/4/2016
                  Science 3/11/2017 3/4/2017', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the number of days between the two dates:

```
days <- as.Date(data$MinEnrollmentDate, format="%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(data$MaxEnrollmentDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

And then add to `MinEnrollmentDate` a random number between 1 and the number of days to the `MaxEnrollmentDate` with the function `sample()`:

```
for(i in seq_along(days)) {
  data[i,4] <- as.character(as.Date(data$MinEnrollmentDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")[i] + sample(1:days[i],1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're working on a data frame named mydata, you could use the following snippet:

```
mydata$sampledate <- sample(seq(as.Date(mydata$MinEnrollmentDate), as.Date(mydata$MinEnrollmentDate), by="day"), 1)
```

basically, what this does is first generate a sequence of all days between the start and end date, and then takes a random sample of size 1 from that sequence, and writes it to your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

A step by step `lubridate` solution, for the sake of completeness (using GGamba's df):

```
if (!require(lubridate)) {
  install.packages("lubridate")
}

df <-  read.table(text = 'Course MinEnrollmentDate MaxEnrollmentDate
                  Maths 3/11/2016 3/4/2016
                  Chemistry 6/11/2016 6/4/2016
                  Physics 9/11/2016 9/4/2016
                  English 12/11/2016 12/4/2016
                  Science 3/11/2017 3/4/2017', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

no_days <- as.POSIXct(df$MinEnrollmentDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y") - as.POSIXct(df$MaxEnrollmentDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

random_days <- sapply(no_days, function(x) sample(x = 1:x, size = 1, replace = T) )

df$random_date <- as.POSIXct(df$MinEnrollmentDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y") + days(random_days)
```